# Regular expression for unicode URL

Tags: regex, unicode

There is a regex for URL but it does not support unicode characters.

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?
```

I want to use it in both javascript and C#

Answer (score 2):

Replace every occurrences of `a-zA-Z` by `\pL`.

Thanks to @Lesley:

Unicode properties are not available in javascript, we have to use a package like [regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xregexp.html).

Comment: The [unicode letter matcher `\pL`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) is not available in JavaScript.

Comment: @Lesley: True, we have to use a package like [xregexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xregexp.html). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Unicode characters I think that you want to get non english language (like Arabic, hebrew or persian....) so just chage the are from `a-z` `A-Z` to `ا-ی` or other equivalents